# After importing mySql database using MysqlBackup.dll all the data base is gibberish

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, database-backups, database-restore

im using mySqlBackup library to backup and restore my database from mySql server uinsg this standard code:

```
string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";
string file = "C:\\backup.sql";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
{
    using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        mb.ImportFromFile(file);
        conn.Close();
    }
}
}
```

After restoring my data base all the data that was written in Hebrew appears like gibberish... 
anyone have an idea to to solve it?

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue. What encoding are you expecting?

Comment: in my data base the encoding is UTF8.
the output file after the backup is ok. but when i import it to mysql then it just all messed up.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify your charset in your connection string. Try adding `CharSet=utf8` as a parameter to the connection string like:

```
string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;CharSet=utf8;";
```

Hopefully your backup is unicode.

Comment: Keep in mind that "Unicode" is encoded many ways. Windows often uses UTF-16, where other platforms prefer UTF-8.

Comment: I have the same problem and I did specify the charset and still the problem continues... any idea how to proceed?